# Memory Leaks in simple nodejs app

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks

Just for fun and to try out nodejs, I wrote a very, very simple program that tests the Collatz Conjecture for an absurd amount of numbers. This, in theory, should be fine. The issue I'm having is that this super simple code has a memory leak and I can't determine why.

```
var step;
var numberOfSteps;
for (var i = 0; i < 100000000000000; i++) {
    step = i;
    numberOfSteps = 0;
    while (step !== 1) {
        if (step%2 === 0)
            step /= 2;
        else
            step = 3 * step + 1;
        numberOfSteps++;
    }
    console.log("" + i + ": " + numberOfSteps + " steps.");
}
```

I've tried the variables both in and out of the loop. I've tried nulling them at the end of the loop. Nothing changes the memory leak.

Comment: Where is the leak? I tried it on my computer and my memory only increased less than 0.01G

Comment: there is no leak ... but the while loop is **infinite** for step === 0 ... though, if you fix that problem, node does seem to keep gobbling up memory slowly, doesn't it

Comment: It's the `console.log` that's causing it - it's almost as if the GC isn't able to run to clean up garbage left behind by the console.log call

Comment: I wasn't able to run it on my case, after 2-3 minutes running it broke and It got crashed:
`FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory
Aborted (core dumped)` (the core dump is bigger).

I was checking the memory usage though, it got incread for about 800mb and later remain stable, it continue running and the crashed with the core-dump above.

Comment: That should be starting i=1, I just have been putting the number I left off in there. Above one it should never go below 1.

Answer (score 1):

Investigating a bit my core dump:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

  131690 ms: Scavenge 1398.1 (1458.1) -> 1398.1 (1458.1) MB, 1.3 / 0 ms (+ 2.8 ms in 1 steps since last GC) [allocation failure] [incremental marking delaying mark-sweep].
  132935 ms: Mark-sweep 1398.1 (1458.1) -> 1398.1 (1458.1) MB, 1245.0 / 0 ms (+ 3.7 ms in 2 steps since start of marking, biggest step 2.8 ms) [last resort gc].
  134169 ms: Mark-sweep 1398.1 (1458.1) -> 1398.1 (1458.1) MB, 1234.5 / 0 ms [last resort gc].


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x33083d8e3ac1 <JS Object>
    1: /* anonymous */ [/user/projects/test.js:~1] [pc=0x557d307b271] (this=0x2a4a669d8341 <an Object with map 0xf8593408359>,exports=0x33083d804189 <undefined>,require=0x33083d804189 <undefined>,module=0x33083d804189 <undefined>,__filename=0x33083d804189 <undefined>,__dirname=0x33083d804189 <undefined>)
    3: _compile [module.js:413] [pc=0x557d304d03c] (this=0x2a4a669d8431...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory
Aborted (core dumped)
```

It seems that this is a known issue about console.log, according to this issue on github https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3171

> This is a known "issue" since writing to stdout in the case of a
>   tty/console is async. So logging a lot of data very fast could very
>   well cause a lot of writes to be buffered in memory if the tty/console
>   cannot keep up.

Answer (score 1):

Here's code which seems to peak at about 50MB for me

This performs the function in lots of 10000 - with a setImmediate to process the next batch

```
function collatz(n) {
    var step,numberOfSteps, i;
    for(i = 0; i < 10000; i++, n++) {
        step = n;
        numberOfSteps = 0;
        while (step !== 1) {
            if (step%2 === 0)
                step /= 2;
            else
                step = 3 * step + 1;
            numberOfSteps++;
        }
        console.log("" + n + ": " + numberOfSteps + " steps.");
    }
    if (n < 100000000000000) {
        setImmediate(collatz, n);
    }
}
collatz(1);
```

Note, in this case you can have the for loop start at 0, because n will start at 1 :p

I haven't tried higher values of the for loop

**I've done some benchmarking against the original code - doing 100 at a time (in the for loop) gives the same performance as 10000, and is indistinguishable in performance from the original code. Even at 10 at a time, I wouldn't be game to say this method is any slower either. Only at 1 at a time is it consistently 5-8% slower than original code**

> Note, I originally thought the issue was garbage collection (or lack thereof) due to the tight loop giving node no time to do any house keeping, but while I was posting the answer, @Svabel posted what seems to be a known issue with hitting console.log hard.
>
> I can only assume that using `setImmediate` allows some sort of house keeping regarding the tty buffers that is otherwise not possible.

Comment: Can you explain why making it asynchronous solves the memory problem?

Comment: not really, I thought it may have been a GC issue, but reading @Svabel's answer, it could be something to do with the "known issue" regarding console.log - I didn't want to include that in my answer as that would seem inappropriate

Comment: interesting, I see in that "issue", the use of `setImmediate` was a proposed solution - one setImmediate per iteration - 10000 per iteration is overkill, even 100 gives similar (actually over a few tests, I can't say it's any worse at all) "performance" to the original code - whereas 1 per iteration does have about an 8% impact on speed